# Get Repository logo found in Github Mobile's Explore feed

Tags: github, github-api, readme

I was surfing through the github app on my phone. In the 'Explore' section, I noticed that there were repositories with their logos on the top
([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnA2P.jpg)). My question is that is there a way to get this image (i.e. the light blue Font Awesome logo in my example) via the Github API. At first, I thought it was just the first image in the repo's ReadMe. But looking at FontAwesome's [repo](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome), that is not the case.